# PHP search results not displaying from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

After submitting the search the results returns a blank result set, nothing returns. Expecting it to return results from mysql search. Was working at one point but I am not sure what I changed to make it stop working.
Site is https://searchsoftball.com/search

I have verified the queries work with MySQL. No connection errors.

```
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "seargobh_c";
$con = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
if( $con->connect_error){
    die('Error: ' . $con->connect_error);
}

if( isset($_GET['search']) ){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
    $sql = "SELECT College.School, City, State, Conference, Division, Main, Softball, Camp FROM College
    inner join Links on Links.School = College.School
    WHERE College.school like '%$name%' or City like '%$name%' or Conference like '%$name%'
    or Division like '%$name%' or State like '%$name%' or Team like '%$name%' order by Division, School desc";
}
$result = $con->query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<label>Search</label>
<form action="search2a.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" placeholder="" name="search">&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Search Softball" name="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
</form>
<h2>Search any of the below</h2>
    <p> Until the search is more robust use these tips:<br>
    Use the full state name<br>
    For division, type out Division 1, etc.<br>
    Searching for California will show schools, state, conference.</p>
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
<tr>
<th>School</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Conference</th>
<th>Division</th>
<th>Main</th>
<th>Softball</th>
<th>Camp</th>    
</tr>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['School']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['City']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['State']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Conference']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Division']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo '<a href="'.$row['Main'].'"target ="_blank">Main</a>'; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo '<a href="'.$row['Softball'].'"target ="_blank">Softball</a>'; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo '<a href="'.$row['Softball'].'"target ="_blank">Softball</a>'; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Results are based on criteria entered in search box. ie. California

Comment: You check for connection errors, but you never check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query.

Comment: Possible problem(idk for sure): Maybe you should declare the table from which your columns are, like: College.School, College.City, College.State,...

Comment: Is it possible that the above code is correct and the issue exists within WordPress?

Comment: Resolved by add error handling to find my query was missing some declares